# Fetch record from a table on date difference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have data like this. Following is the sample data.

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img695/441/custoemrids.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img695/441/custoemrids.png)

I want to get all those CustomerIDs which has date diff of 2 hours in DateCreated of Enquiry.

For example CustomerId 10602 has 3 enquiries . If the time difference is 2 hours in any of these three enquiries then this CustomerId should be in my result set. Same for the other Customers.

Thanks

Comment: I don't completely understand your question.  Can you tell us your expected results?

Comment: DateCreated is 2 hours "different" from what? (If current date/time, looks like all your sample data would be selected.)

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve all rows where the DateCreated value is within 2 hours of the current time? Against what do you want to compare the DateCreated values?

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for the inconvenience you face to understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This presumes that EnquiryId is the PK of the table. I also presumed you want to count items *within* two hours of each other.

```
Select Distinct T1.CustomerId
From Table As T1
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Table As T2
                Where T2.CustomerId = T1.CustomerId
                    And T2.EnquiryId <> T1.EnquiryId
                    And Abs(DateDiff(hh, T1.DateCreated, T2.DateCreated)) <= 2
               )
```

Comment: @Ardman - Yeah. Fixed that in my post rather than via a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [CustomerId]
  FROM [Table]
 WHERE [DateCreated] >= DATEADD(hour, -2, GETDATE())
   AND [CustomerId] = xxx;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The difference should be among enquiries of same Customer not with current date.

Comment: Ah, you want Thomas's answer then. :o)

Comment: @Ardman thanks for the answer. Your answer is correct, my question was ambiguous.